# An error saying "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" shows up when I run my code

Tags: java, exception, multidimensional-array

Here is my code:

```
    Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
    
    int[][] anArray= new int[2][2];
    int[][] anArray1= new int[2][2];
    int[][] anArray2= new int[2][2];
    int temp1=1, temp2=1;
    
    for(int a=0; a<anArray.length; a++){
        for(int b=0; b<anArray.length; b++){
            System.out.println("Enter value in anArray index["+a+"]["+b+"]:");
            anArray[a][b]= input.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("Enter value in anArray1 index["+a+"]["+b+"]:");
            anArray[a][b]= input.nextInt();
        }
    for(int c=0; c<anArray2.length; c++){
        for(int d=0; d<anArray2.length; d++){
            anArray2[c][d]=anArray[c][d] + anArray1[temp1][temp2];
            System.out.println("Total of "+ anArray[c][d]+ " and "+ anArray1[temp1][temp2]+ " is " + anArray2[c][d]);
        temp2--;
    }
        temp1--;
        temp2=1;
    }
    }
```

This is a laboratory from my class. And once I simulated it, I don't quite get these parts of the code where it involved temp1 and temp2

```
    int temp1=1, temp2=1;

    anArray2[c][d]=anArray[c][d] + anArray1[temp1][temp2];
```

The line of error is here:

```
    anArray2[c][d]=anArray[c][d] + anArray1[temp1][temp2];
```

Please helpppp

Comment: java indices for an array have valid: 0 -> array.length-1. -1 is not a valid index, that's your problem.

Comment: you are subtracting values in your for loops, values you use as index, that's likely the issue.

Comment: In your own words, what do you think the error message means? In your own words, if an array has a length of N, exactly what numbers do you think should be valid indices into the array? What happened when you tried using a debugger to check the values that you use to index into the array? Do they make sense to you? Are they what you expected? If not, can you understand how the computation goes wrong? What happened when you tried to trace through the logic of the computation?

Comment: temp1 is becoming -1 which leads to ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, so, check your logic.

Comment: @Stultuske so is my professor's code wrong then? He was the one who coded it.

Comment: If this code is trying to reference element -1 of an array, then whoever wrote this code made a mistake.

Comment: Can someone please explain to me why my professor put decrement on temp1 and temp2? Because he said in the instruction is that the code is just asking the user to input values on the indices and let us find out the output, then I run the program and it says that error.

Comment: I guess I was right that the code has a mistake and not my brain lol, I'll just tell my professor. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

`System.out.println("Enter value in anArray1 index["+a+"]["+b+"]:");                     anArray[a][b]= input.nextInt();`

You typed `anArray[a][b] = input.nextInt();` instead of `anArray1[a][b] = input.nextInt();`